# Is there a way to put an ArrayList into a 5x5 array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I assume I run through the `ArrayList`, but do I have to give them positions in the array or can I fill it automatically? What would be the easiest way to combine the array and `ArrayList`?

Comment: Do you mean a 2D array?

Comment: what are you asking? con you show us what you mean? what do you want to fill and with what and what do you want to combine and with what?

Comment: An example could be very useful.

Comment: characters are in the arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo:

```
int i=0;
for(Foo f:fooList){
    fooArr[i/5][i%5]=f;
    i++;
}
```

Not the cleanest, but it works and has a few lessons involved.

If there are too many elements in the list, you'll get an exception, for one. Diving integers and how modulo works are two more tidbits here,